# Can not delete cached item created with beginCache

Tags: php, caching, yii

I have a fragment that I'm caching because there are a lot of database hits to generate the content.

main.php:

```
    'cache'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.caching.CFileCache'
    )
```

view.php

```
<?php if($this->beginCache("my_id", array('duration' => 315360000))) { ?>
   // lots of heavy stuff
<?php $this->endCache(); } ?>
```

My cached fragment only changes when I adjust the configuration in a database table. I'm trying to find a way to delete the cached item using the "my_id". The Yii documentation is somewhat misleading because when it talks about `beginCache` it refers to the key ("my_id"), but when it talks about deleting items from the cache it also talks about the key, but it is not the same key!
`beginCache` is essentially a wrapper for an `COutputCache` widget and so "my_id" is not the key used in the cache.

Does anyone know how to convert "my_id" into a cache-friendly key so that I can delete that specific item from the cache.

I've tried extending from `CFileCache` but my key is generated from `COutputCache` which uses `CFileCache` and I don't think there is a back route. I have also tried beginning a widget with an overloaded version of `COutputCache` which works but just seems like a really nasty hack.

```
    $properties = array();
    $properties['id']=Yii::app()->params["cache_name_matrix"];
    $cache=$this->beginWidget('MyCOutputCache',$properties);
    $key = $cache->getKeyHack();
```

My current work around is flush the whole cache but this gets rid of everything and seems a little bit heavy handed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

COutputCache calculates the cache key using protected method called **[getCacheKey](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/web/widgets/COutputCache.php#L277)** which internally calls **[getBaseCacheKey](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/web/widgets/COutputCache.php#L266)** and then depending on specified variations transforms it. In your, the simplest case, with no variations, I believe it will end up with something like 'Yii.COutputCache.my_id.......' where 'Yii.COutputCache.' is COutputCache::CACHE_KEY_PREFIX. Take a look at the [code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/web/widgets/COutputCache.php#L277) of this method.

So, knowing this, you technically can delete your fragment manually. But I strongly encourage you to take a look at mechanism of dependencies described in the [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.fragment#caching-options). You said you invalidate this fragment if something changes in your database, so probably **[CDbCacheDependency](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCacheDependency)** is what you need.

Comment: 1st paragraph: that is basically the same as my nasty hack. There doesn't seem to be a way of accessing the COutputCache from CFileCache so you have to assume COutputCache is used and generate the file name yourself. 2nd paragraph: I'm using this but it isn't want I want because the cost is too high. There are loads of places I need to check and the cache-alive query is complicated and must be done each request. Sorry I can't accept this answer as I want to delete cached item directly as it still seems a better way. Looks like I'll have to implement it myself, unless someone already has!

Comment: Up voted because I ended up using CDbCacheDependency, but it is still not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 try this

```
$key = Array ('yii\widgets\FragmentCache','key_id');
Yii::$app->cache->delete($key);
```